# Android 2.3 - debugger stops when retrofit caller is being initialized error #jdi internalexception unexpected jdwp error 103

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-studio-2.3

Initializing caller with the method of endpoints it just stops the debugger and application stops unexpectedly. There is no logcat or something that might help me to find the cause of error. All I can see is this:

```
*com sun jdi internalexception unexpected jdwp error 103 intellij.*
```

This is the code snippet where the crash it's happening:

```
*private Call<FUHRRAPPORTCHILDSerializer> getRouteDetailsCaller = endpoints.getRouteChildDetails("", "", "");*
```

Does anybody have a clue about this `IntelliJ IDEA` bug?

Comment: this is not a itenllij bug, i think it is from retrofit. it also happened to me, and after one day of debugging it just disappeared and i really did not modify a thing, Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes I solved it, I realized that the problem was at emulator **Nexus 5x API 26**, when I ran it on emulator with **API 25** or any other real device it's okay now, thank you very much @Olcay for your response.